# Model property object not received in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to access the property "Locality" of the Model "Address" in the controller.
If I try to assign value, it gives me error : **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** 
Model:

```
public class Profile
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public int FlatNumber { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Locality { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Details(Profile pf)
    {
        pf.Address.Locality = "abc";
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@model DownloadFileTest.Models.Profile
     <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight:bold">ID</td>
                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Id)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight:bold">Name</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Name, new { @class = "form-control fact", @disabled = "true" })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight:bold">Flat number( Large, Medium and Small)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(Model => Model.Address.FlatNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, rows = "3", cols = "50", @disabled = "true", @class = "fact" })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight:bold">Street</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Address.Street, new { @class = "form-control fact", @disabled = "true" })</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

On your View you have all `Address` properties marked as `@disabled = "true"` thus when you POST your form - nothing is posting. That's why MVC model binder don't bind anything and you got `null` in `Address` property of `Profile` class.

You can fix it like this:

```
 public ActionResult Details(Profile pf)
 {
     pf.Address = new Address();
     pf.Address.Locality = "abc";
     return View();
 }
```

Or even do it like this:

```
public class Profile
{
    public Profile()
    {
        Address = new Address(); //here
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}
```

Note that parametless constructor will be called before binding process so if you will someday POST Address values it will bind correctly.

Comment: The first solution worked. But I need to read the view data in controller. How to do that?

Comment: @MonikaSingh it's better to ask another question - will be faster

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the model to the View

```
public ActionResult Details(Profile pf)
{
    pf.Address.Locality = "abc";
    return View(pf);
}
```

To get data back to controller you need to implement a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("myActionName", "MyControllerName", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold">ID</td>
                <td>@Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Id)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold">Name</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Name, new { @class = "form-control fact", @disabled = "true" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold">Flat number( Large, Medium and Small)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(Model => Model.Address.FlatNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, rows = "3", cols = "50", @disabled = "true", @class = "fact" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold">Street</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Address.Street, new { @class = "form-control fact", @disabled = "true" })</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Submit" />
    }
```

In the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(Profile pf)
{
    // My Stuff
    return View();
}
```

[Some reading on binding](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710776/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-An-Absol)

Comment: I want to access the data entered by user in controller.